# Scope on Tasks inside SubProcess

Tags: java, spring, business-process-management, bpmn, camunda

I have a process with a subprocess just like below:

**UserTask1 -> SubProcess(ServiceTask1 -> ServiceTask2) -> UserTask5 -> End**
The SubProcess is configured as multi instance with collection and element variable, I can get the element variable value using local variables on ServiceTask2 through executionId on DelegateExecution.id but with the same code on ServiceTask2 I get nothing, only if I use the DelegateExecution.parentId. Debugging the code I realized that DelegateExecution on ServiceTask1 come with SubProcess ExecutionId and on ServiceTask2 the DelegateExecution come with its own ExecutionId and SubProcess is its parentId, it seems just the ServiceTask2 is right. I can't use the same code for ServiceTask1 and ServiceTask2. Is that a bug or I'm doing something wrong?

Full process xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<bpmn2:definitions xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:bpmn2="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL" xmlns:bpmndi="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/DI" xmlns:camunda="http://activiti.org/bpmn" xmlns:dc="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DC" xmlns:di="http://www.omg.org/spec/DD/20100524/DI" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.omg.org/spec/BPMN/20100524/MODEL BPMN20.xsd" id="_6RXjgBy9EeSVeKdg6gA1kA" exporter="camunda modeler" exporterVersion="2.6.0" targetNamespace="http://activiti.org/bpmn">
  <bpmn2:process id="com.Campaign" name="Campanha" isExecutable="true">
    <bpmn2:subProcess id="subProcess" name="subProcess">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_14</bpmn2:outgoing>
      <bpmn2:multiInstanceLoopCharacteristics camunda:collection="${conceptIdList}" camunda:elementVariable="conceptId"/>
      <bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_2">
        <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_4</bpmn2:outgoing>
      </bpmn2:startEvent>
      <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_4" name="" sourceRef="StartEvent_2" targetRef="ServiceTask1"/>
      <bpmn2:serviceTask id="ServiceTask1" camunda:delegateExpression="${customLogHandler}" name="ServiceTask1">
        <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_4</bpmn2:incoming>
        <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_9</bpmn2:outgoing>
      </bpmn2:serviceTask>
      <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_9" name="" sourceRef="ServiceTask1" targetRef="ServiceTask2"/>
      <bpmn2:serviceTask id="ServiceTask2" camunda:delegateExpression="${customLogHandler}" name="ServiceTask2">
        <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_9</bpmn2:incoming>
        <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_65</bpmn2:outgoing>
      </bpmn2:serviceTask>
      <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_65" name="" sourceRef="ServiceTask2" targetRef="EndEvent_13"/>
      <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_13">
        <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_65</bpmn2:incoming>
      </bpmn2:endEvent>
    </bpmn2:subProcess>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_14" name="" sourceRef="subProcess" targetRef="UserTask2"/>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask1" camunda:assignee="bruno" name="UserTask1">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_3</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_3" name="" sourceRef="UserTask1" targetRef="subProcess"/>
    <bpmn2:startEvent id="StartEvent_1">
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_2</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:startEvent>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_2" sourceRef="StartEvent_1" targetRef="UserTask1"/>
    <bpmn2:userTask id="UserTask2" camunda:assignee="bruno" name="UserTask2">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_14</bpmn2:incoming>
      <bpmn2:outgoing>SequenceFlow_17</bpmn2:outgoing>
    </bpmn2:userTask>
    <bpmn2:sequenceFlow id="SequenceFlow_17" name="" sourceRef="UserTask2" targetRef="EndEvent_5"/>
    <bpmn2:endEvent id="EndEvent_5">
      <bpmn2:incoming>SequenceFlow_17</bpmn2:incoming>
    </bpmn2:endEvent>
  </bpmn2:process>
  <bpmn2:message id="Message_1" name="msgAjustarConceito"/>
  <bpmn2:message id="Message_2" name="msgCotacaoGerada"/>
  <bpmn2:message id="Message_3" name="msgCatalogoGerado"/>
  <bpmn2:message id="Message_4" name="msgSolicitarRFQ"/>
  <bpmn2:signal id="Signal_1" name="msgAjusteConceito"/>
  <bpmn2:message id="Message_5" name="msgNewMaterial"/>
  <bpmn2:message id="Message_6" name="msgCampanhaFinalizada"/>
  <bpmndi:BPMNDiagram id="BPMNDiagram_1">
    <bpmndi:BPMNPlane id="BPMNPlane_1" bpmnElement="com.Campaign">
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_21" bpmnElement="StartEvent_1">
        <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="18.0" y="86.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="36.0" y="127.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_UserTask_29" bpmnElement="UserTask1">
        <dc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="108.0" y="64.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_2" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_2" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_21" targetElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_29">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="54.0" y="104.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="108.0" y="104.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="79.0" y="104.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_SubProcess_3" bpmnElement="subProcess" isExpanded="true">
        <dc:Bounds height="178.0" width="528.0" x="265.0" y="15.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_3" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_3" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_29" targetElement="_BPMNShape_SubProcess_3">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="208.0" y="104.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="265.0" y="104.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="6.0" width="6.0" x="230.0" y="104.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_22" bpmnElement="StartEvent_2">
        <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="285.0" y="93.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="303.0" y="134.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_SendTask_17" bpmnElement="ServiceTask1">
        <dc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="371.0" y="71.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_4" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_4" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_StartEvent_22" targetElement="_BPMNShape_SendTask_17">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="321.0" y="111.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="371.0" y="111.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="6.0" width="6.0" x="343.0" y="111.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_SendTask_18" bpmnElement="ServiceTask2">
        <dc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="564.0" y="71.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_UserTask_33" bpmnElement="UserTask2">
        <dc:Bounds height="80.0" width="100.0" x="876.0" y="64.0"/>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_14" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_14" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_SubProcess_3" targetElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_33">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="793.0" y="104.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="876.0" y="104.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="6.0" width="6.0" x="815.0" y="104.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_EndEvent_27" bpmnElement="EndEvent_13">
        <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="720.0" y="93.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="738.0" y="134.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_65" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_65" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_SendTask_18" targetElement="_BPMNShape_EndEvent_27">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="664.0" y="111.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="720.0" y="111.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="6.0" width="6.0" x="692.0" y="111.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_9" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_9" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_SendTask_17" targetElement="_BPMNShape_SendTask_18">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="471.0" y="111.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="564.0" y="111.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="6.0" width="6.0" x="515.0" y="111.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
      <bpmndi:BPMNShape id="_BPMNShape_EndEvent_33" bpmnElement="EndEvent_5">
        <dc:Bounds height="36.0" width="36.0" x="1035.0" y="86.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="0.0" width="0.0" x="1053.0" y="127.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNShape>
      <bpmndi:BPMNEdge id="BPMNEdge_SequenceFlow_17" bpmnElement="SequenceFlow_17" sourceElement="_BPMNShape_UserTask_33" targetElement="_BPMNShape_EndEvent_33">
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="976.0" y="104.0"/>
        <di:waypoint xsi:type="dc:Point" x="1035.0" y="104.0"/>
        <bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
          <dc:Bounds height="6.0" width="6.0" x="998.0" y="104.0"/>
        </bpmndi:BPMNLabel>
      </bpmndi:BPMNEdge>
    </bpmndi:BPMNPlane>
  </bpmndi:BPMNDiagram>
</bpmn2:definitions>
```

Comment: Please post the subprocess snippet of your BPMN 2.0 xml.

Comment: Included full process xml. The subProcesses are generated correctly just to access the elementVariable conceptId is different on ServiceTask1 and ServiceTask2.

Comment: Could you please add the version of camunda bpm you are using and the code of your delegateExpression?